# What's Agatha's final fate?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

**Spoilers for *WandaVision* finale**:

At the end of the finale, Wanda transforms Agatha into her sitcom version "Agnes". However, by the end, Wanda removes the hex and so the "sitcom" characters are back to normal in the city.

But what about Agnes? Shouldn't she transform back to Agatha or is it part of the Scarlet Witch powers now to trap only her in her specific "Agnes" form?

Comment: Don't try to explain away every plot hole in Marvel movies. It can only end in frustration.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: or don't reflexively call things plot holes when they're not, just because someone had a question about them.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Sure, sure, but see the discussion in the comment under AJ’s answer. You really need to bend backwards to *not* consider this (or other points) a plot hole. The Marvel movies are just generally not well-known for putting a large premium on consistency, they happily ignore or retcon inconvenient facts. They’re good yarn, but they’re not a masterclass in great story-telling.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: sure. It's like the writers just decided *magic* could solve it!

Comment: @KonradRudolph: "they're not a masterclass in great story-telling" — and automatically squeaking "plot hole" every time someone asks about the details of how fictional fantastical magic systems work isn't a particularly great example of interesting or illuminating critical discussion either. If we spend all our time assessing fictional works based on what they're not, rather than what they are, we're not going to enjoy many of them.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite “automatically squeaking "plot hole" […] isn't a particularly great example of interesting or illuminating critical discussion” — Agreed. But *I’m not doing that*. I’ve specifically commented on a question which (see discussion below) *clearly relates to a plot hole*. In general such questions (including this one! — I upvoted it) are totally fine. I just caution against overzealous post-hoc rationalisation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't see how this is a plot hole at all. Either it's a mistake from Wanda and a setup for future works. Or, and more likely, makes total sense. Agatha was not part of the hex so could not be undone by it... simple as that.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Then … where does she live? You saw the comments below. It doesn’t make sense. Whether she was part of the spell/hex is not that relevant. Anyway, I don’t think this mistake is particularly egregious, it definitely didn’t spoil my enjoyment of the show. But it also doesn’t reflexively need to be defended.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Where does she live is a perfectly valid question and something that's not explored in the show. There are various options but we never see. How she was able to be controlled even though the hex was broken, which the question is about, is explained (even if not explicitly). Neither, however, are plot holes.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> But what about Agnes?

She is still there living as a nosy neighbor in Westview.

> Shouldn't she transform back to Agatha or is it part of the Scarlet Witch powers now to trap only her in her specific "Agnes" form?

She was never part of the hex.

Scarlet Witch or Wanda has the power to manipulate others' minds as we have seen in *Age of Ultron* and this show. Agatha was never really affected by Wanda's mind manipulation powers and she was never really part of the hex as we see when she reveals her original form in episode 7.

So, near the end of the season finale, Wanda takes her power, wipes her mind, and makes her the same nosy neighbor she pretended to be. Therefore Agnes wasn't transformed back to Agatha when the hex was removed.

Comment: But like, does she have a house? A job? Is she just going to sleep on a bench when night rolls around? Did she also manipulate Bohner into thinking she's his wife?

Comment: With the runes seemingly etched on the walls of the hex and the hex gone, does that mean that Agatha technically isn't powerless any more, should she somehow regain her memory of who she really is?

Comment: @Michael almost certainly she'd have her powers back.  Hard to see how she'd get her memory back though.  Maybe if she happened to wander into the basement?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Well, of course, she has the house as we see in the 6th episode. I can't confirm about the job though. She could have manipulated Bohner like fake Pietro so maybe yes.

Comment: @Michael Wanda took her power and wiped her mind. So it's unlikely for her to get her powers back when the hex was gone. There could be other ways for it to happen. However, it all depends on the writers.

Comment: @AJ The house was Bohner's.  Agatha just moved in and used Bohner.

Comment: An important thing to add: _"Once cast, a spell can never be changed."_ - Agatha was not part of the original hex so could not be added to it. This just backs up that Wanda's spell on her was completely separate to the hex.

Answer (score 16):

### Agatha still lives in Westview.

Westview has has reverted to its original state but Agatha has been changed by Wanda's magic.

(Edited for brevity)

> WANDA: Mmm-hmm. I’ll give you the role you chose. The nosy neighbor.
>
> AGATHA:You… You have… You have no idea what you’ve unleashed. You’re gonna need me.
>
> WANDA: If I do, **I know where to find you.**
>
> WANDA: **You live here now.** No one will ever bother you.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with AJ's answer for the immediate near future. If Wanda had the power to manipulate an entire town full of people, she can certainly independently do it to one person.

Long term, we can probably perform some Marvel Kremlinology here. In the comics Agatha is known for teaching others magic, and that includes Scarlet Witch ([Avengers #128](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers_Vol_1_128)). Of course she's generally portrayed as benevolent in the comics as well, which makes her Wandavision portrayal a bit of a departure.

She was also involved in the eventual creation of Wanda's children. Given that one of them ended up being on the [Young Avengers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Avengers) team, and we've already seen appearances by two other members of that team in the MCU (Cassie Lang and Kate Bishop), its quite possible they will reappear in some form eventually.

The Wandavision dialog bits about Wanda needing to learn and Agatha offering to teach her, very strongly implies (via the scriptwriting principle of [Chekhov's Gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chekhov%27s_gun)) that they are planning to have that happen sometime in the future.

So indications are that the current plan is that Agatha will spend at least some time in the future teaching and/or mentoring Wanda in magic. There's also a decent possibility she will end up being involved in the reintroduction of at least one of Wanda's children.

Comment: As a bit of an update, we have now also seen [Eli Bradley](https://www.cinemablend.com/television/2565076/falcon-winter-soldier-patriot-eli-bradley-elijah-richardson) (Patriot) in Falcon & Winter Soldier. The only founding member still missing is Hulkling, and given the number of Skrulls running around the MCU, he wouldn't exactly be difficult to dig up if needed.

Answer (score -1):

#### Agatha is Agnes, but...

As you mentioned, the hex around the town is gone. On top of that, viewers pointed out that her witch brooch that she got from her mother is still on her. Also, there is no mention of what happened to her rabbit/familiar.

These things, plus the fact that she's a powerful witch, suggest that her prison is not as permanent as Wanda thinks.

It seems quite likely that Agatha will return as a villain.

Bonus—she was loved by the viewers, so there's an out-of-universe reason to bring her back too.

Comment: Is there any indication that there will be another season?  The finale did a very good job of wrapping up the whole premise of the show, which means they'd have to start over.  Unless the intent is to bring her back in a new Avengers movie.

Comment: @MarkRansom official answer is [neither yes nor no](https://collider.com/wandavision-season-2-kevin-feige-disney-plus/)

Comment: I'd predict at least an Agnes featurette on the _Multiverse of Madness_ bonus disk.

Comment: It sounds rather like the continuation of this story line will be happening in the upcoming Doctor Strange feature. I do agree with @PeterTurner that this would be a good time to revisit Agatha, but they'll have trouble squeezing in the minutes to do so. I'm not sure how much hardcopy disks are A Thing anymore though. Perhaps a post-credit scene?

Comment: I think the brooch is like the pocket watch in Doctor Who.  It will be the key to accessing and/or restoring her memories and power.

Comment: Marvel has announced a spinoff-series (!) entitled [*Agatha: House of Harkness*](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Agatha:_House_of_Harkness), coming in the '23-'24 season;  so fans will be getting some Agatha even if they don't get more *WandaVision.*